# Fatal Erro: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object

Tags: apex, json, callout, jsongenerator

I need help please, how do I make a template class for this Json, I've tried several ways but I'm getting the message that the Json is malformed.

```
[
{
    "tipo": "PECÚLIO POR MORTE - RISCO",
    "beneficiarios": [
        {
            "idade": 60,
            "nascimento": "0000-00-00",
            "parentesco": "PAIS",
            "percentualRateio": 50,
            "cpf": "12312312345",
            "nome": "L***MASC***",
            "id": 3449190,
            "sexo": "FEMININO"
        },
        {
            "idade": 38,
            "nascimento": "0000-01-00",
            "parentesco": "IRMÃO",
            "percentualRateio": 50,
            "cpf": "12312312365",
            "nome": "S***MASC***",
            "id": 3449188,
            "sexo": "MASCULINO"
        }
    ],
    "valorBeneficio": 46100.83,
    "valorPagamento": 79.13,
    "status": "SUSPENSO"
},
{
    "tipo": "RENDA MENSAL VITALÍCIA - SOBREVIVENCIA",
    "idadeSaida": 65,
    "beneficiarios": [
        {
            "idade": 38,
            "nascimento": "0000-01-00",
            "parentesco": "IRMÃO",
            "percentualRateio": 50,
            "cpf": "12312312378",
            "nome": "S***MASC***",
            "id": 3449188,
            "sexo": "MASCULINO"
        },
        {
            "idade": 63,
            "nascimento": "0000-07-00",
            "parentesco": "PAIS",
            "percentualRateio": 50,
            "cpf": "12312312378",
            "nome": "L***MASC***",
            "id": 3449190,
            "sexo": "FEMININO"
        }
    ],
    "valorBeneficio": 0,
    "dataSaida": "2053-10-23",
    "valorPagamento": 0,
    "status": "SUSPENSO"
    }
]
```

My Class:

```
public with sharing class ConsultationBeneficiaryModels {

public class JSON2Apex {
    @AuraEnabled public String tipo;        
    @AuraEnabled public Double valorBeneficio;
    public List<Beneficiarios> beneficiarios;
    @AuraEnabled public Double valorPagamento;
    @AuraEnabled public String status;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer idadeSaida;
    @AuraEnabled public String dataSaida;
}
public class Beneficiarios {
    @AuraEnabled public Integer idade;
    @AuraEnabled public String nascimento;
    @AuraEnabled public String parentesco;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer percentualRateio;
    @AuraEnabled public String cpf;
    @AuraEnabled public String nome;
    @AuraEnabled public Integer id;
    @AuraEnabled public String sexo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON that starts with `[` and ends with `]` is an array (Apex List). You need to decode it as such:

```
List<ConsultationBeneficiaryModels.JSON2Apex> results = 
  (List<ConsultationBeneficiaryModels.JSON2Apex>)
  JSON.deserialize(
    jsonString, 
    List<ConsultationBeneficiaryModels.JSON2Apex>.class
  );
```

Comment: Resolved, I got the correct return. Thank you very much.